# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' (Python)

Tags: python, pip, python-import, file-structure

I know this question has been asked multiple times before although, even after using absolute paths I can't get past this import error

I want to import `extensions` from `functions.py`

**functions.py**

```
from src.Categorize_CLI.extensions import *
```

**Error**

```
(.venv) PS D:\Python\Categorize-CLI> & d:/Python/Categorize-CLI/.venv/Scripts/python.exe d:/Python/Categorize-CLI/src/Categorize_CLI/services/key_functions.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Categorize-CLI\src\Categorize_CLI\services\key_functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.Categorize_CLI.extensions import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

**Update**

I removed the `src` folder making `Categorize_CLI` the top level module, but I still get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Categorize-CLI\Categorize_CLI\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from services.functions import *
  File "d:\Python\Categorize-CLI\Categorize_CLI\services\functions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from secondary_functions import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'secondary_functions'
```

This error is from running `main.py`

**import statement in main.py**

```
from services.functions import *
```

**Current file structure**

```
Categorize-CLI
├── Categorize_CLI
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── extensions.py
│   │   ├── functions.py
│   │   ├── secondary_functions.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── .gitignore
```

How I am importing `extensions` from `secondary_functions`:

```
from extensions import *
```

Comment: have you tried `from ..extensions import *` ? Your src is not declared as a module.

Comment: Yes but I get this error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: You should declare a top level module. Can you modify your file structure ? Some conventions are not respected here.

Comment: My current file structure is the standard file structure for a python package or at-least I hope so, you can view the project here: https://github.com/Rohith-JN/Categorize-CLI. I am not sure what you meant by top level module

Comment: when I hover over the import statement in vscode, the message box specifies src as a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to clone your project to try understand what"s happening. I didn't understand clearly your file structure from the image in your question.

1. You don't need to declare `src` as a module. Your top level module should be `Categorize_CLI` (`src/Categorize_CLI`). You should remove the `src/__init__.py`.
2. Since `secondary_functions.py` and `extensions.py` are both already in top level module, you don't need to name it to refer to it,  you can simply import `extensions` in `secondary_functions` with

```py
# secondary_functions.py
from extensions import *
```

This works if you use `from secondary_functions import *` in your `main.py`

Comment: So basically I have to remove the `__init__.py` file inside `src`?

Comment: Yes remove it and don't try to use `src` as a module. Your top parent module is `Categorize_CLI`. Then just import in `secondary_functions.py` with the `from extensions import *` statement. It worked like that for me when I cloned your project.

Comment: I removed the `src` folder and made `Categorize_CLI` the top level module, But I still get another error

Comment: I moved `secondary_functions` and `extensions` into the `services` folder

Comment: If they are both in the same submodule you should be good with `from .extensions import *` (with the dot before extensions)

Comment: I have update my file structure, can you take a look at my latest commit in my git repo?

Comment: You removed your top level module ? That doesn't look good... `src` should just be the containing directory of your entire package source code.

Comment: @RohithNambiar I sent you a pull request on your repo with the fix.

Comment: There is a new problem, when I uploaded the package to test pypi and after installing it and running it, I got the error: `src module not found in __main__`. Although when I locally installed the package using this command `pip install --executable .` it worked

Comment: sorry `pip install --editable .` actually

Comment: I assume that's because you didn't modify the line `mod = __import__(f"src.Categorize_CLI.commands.{name}", None, None, ["main"])` in your `__main__.py`. Or maybe you still have other imports trying to refer to `src` as the parent package.

Comment: I did all of that but I still get the same error, is there any way to test the package if it works without having to upload it to test.pypi ?

Comment: You can install it locally, `pip install ./path/to/your/script.py`

Comment: I migrated the project to `poetry`